# Software for linux like Dreamweaver which opens related files like css, js and php included with main file?

Tags: linux, web-development, ide

In *Adobe Dreamweaver* when I write HTML code and insert `style.css` and `script.js` as an example, it will open those both files also in a bar, so if I'm searching for a CSS class it will be easy to find by selecting open documents in the "find and replace" box.

I'm thinking to move on to Linux, but this feature is very much important for me. Can any one suggest an IDE which has this feature of opening related files?

#### Requirements:

- IDE supporting PHP, HTML, CSS and JS
- code folding
- code completion for HTML tags and CSS properties
- opens dependencies automatically, i.e. `.js`/`.css` files are opened in separate (sub-) windows when the `.html` file opened declares them
- runs on Linux natively

#### Nice to have (optional, not really needed):

- WYSIWYG editor is not necessary.
- code highlighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest thing I've found is another Adobe product called [Adobe Brackets](http://brackets.io).  The only thing it's not featuring is the opening of links.  It's not exact, but it's the closest thing I've seen.

There is a [discussion about the missing feature](https://trello.com/c/I0TQSICd/549-jump-to-script-css-file-s-source-from-html-script-link-tag) but it's dated.

Comment: Yes, i have used it, but that's the only feature of dreamweaver missing from brackets.Hope they add it in future sprints. Thanks anyway.